# Angular: scaling element of component to remaining viewport height without scroll

Tags: html, css, angular, single-page-application

I have an Angular single-page application with a shell component that contains a `<router-outlet>`, and a `<mat-toolbar>` header with height defined at 7vh.

[image]

Within a child component, I want to include a JavaScript D3 map that automatically scales to the remaining height of the viewport without requiring vertical scroll.

I have included a `<div>` wrapper for the map with red background. This is the element I would want to automatically rescale to take up the remaining available viewport height.

**app.component.html**:

```
<!--HEADER-->
<mat-toolbar role="banner" class="flexSpaceBetween">
  <span *ngIf="screenWidth >= 840">
    <button mat-raised-button
            class="menuBtn"
            (click)="toggle()">
      <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
      Menu
    </button>
  </span>
</mat-toolbar>

<!--LARGE SCREEN: SIDEBAR-->
<mat-sidenav-container *ngIf="screenWidth >= 840" class="fullPage" autosize>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav
               mode="side"
               class="mat-elevation-z3"
               [opened]="screenWidth >= 840">
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content class="component">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**app.component.css**:

```
mat-toolbar {
  height: 7vh;
  background-color: #343a40;
  font-weight: 350;
}
.fullPage {
  height: 93vh;
}
.component {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 2%;
}
```

**home.component.html**:

```
<h3>TEST COMPONENT HEADER</h3>
<hr>
<div class="testing">
  testing
</div>
```

**home.component.css**:

```
.testing {
  background-color: red;
}
```

I have attempted to add `height: 100%` and `height: 100vh`, but both of these cause the testing element to grow larger than remaining height, requiring scroll. What is the best method of accomplishing this?

Comment: Use `display:flex` and `flex-grow:1`. It's the only display value that supports what you're after

Comment: @Pieterjan this does not seem to account for the outer app.component, and causes the map to stretch vertically to a point triggering automatic scroll.